# How to set screen contrast using Ubuntu 12.04 on Macbook Pro?

Tags: 12.04, macbook-pro, color-management

I have a Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It works fine with all the required packages. The only thing I see which is weird is colors are way too light. I think this is contrast ratio which I need to set. How can I adjust contrast ratio on Ubuntu?

**sudo lshw -c video** gives following output.

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d301ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense given laptop monitors normally don't come with contrast ratio settings. You need to install xcalib if you want to manually change your gamma/contrast ratio/backlight.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xcalib.1.html